# How to create random data but with meaningful relation?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, data-structures

```
    var lc_relationship={"sensor1":[
        {
            "ObjectID":"sens1_001",
            "Parent":null,
            "child": sens2_050
            "z cordinate": -5
        },
        {
            "ObjectID":"sens1_002",
            "Parent":null,
            "child": sens2_072
            "z cordinate": -5

        }
       .
       .
       .
   uptill ObjectID : sens1_100
],
"sensor2":[
        {
             "ObjectID":"sens2_001",
            "Parent":sens1_068,
            "child": sens3_010
            "z cordinate": 0 

        },
        {
            "ObjectID":"sens2_002",
            "Parent":sens1_040,
            "child": sens3_080
            "z cordinate": 0

        }
       .
       .
       .
   uptill ObjectID : sens2_100
],
"sensor3":[
        {
            "ObjectID":"sens3_001",
            "Parent":sens2_055,
            "child": null
            "z cordinate": 5

        },
        {
            "ObjectID":"sens3_002",
            "Parent":sens2_029,
            "child": null
            "z cordinate": 5

        }
       .
       .
       .
   uptill ObjectID : sens3_100
]
```

}

[image]

I need to store the relationship of geometry in some data structure so that later should be helpful to track either wise to access the derived geometry. I made a detail picture, so that one could get the better idea. Could someone help..?

Comment: I am a little confused. Do you want random data, or do you want geometric data? How is the data being collected? Is there a data structure already in place? Can you be a little more descriptive of the problem at hand please?

Comment: we did not invented mass production real 3d screens...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question, you have *very concrete* data (100 *cones* placed in 3 layers), and what you want to randomize is the relationship between them.

If so, then next code may give you what you need: It randomly picks a *cone* from first layer, then sets a relation to a randomly selected *cone* from the second layer, for which also sets a relation to a randomly selected *cone* from the third layer (no *cone* is selected twice in any layer, as in your description). Here is a jsFiddle with a working implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/roimergarcia/j2uLE.

NOTES:

- The 10x10 grid that is on the drawing may be easily generated form the indexes of the *sensor* arrays.
- If you are going to generate more than 100 cones per layer (100000?) or a lot of layers, you may need to optimize this algorithm.

```js
//A helping function
function rightPad(number) {
    var tmpStr = number.toString();
    return ("000" + tmpStr).substring(tmpStr.length, tmpStr.length+3);
}

//The generator function 
function generateData(){

    var nSize = 100,
        lc_relationship,
        aSensor1 = [],
        aSensor2 = [],
        aSensor3 = [],

    lc_relationship = {
        "sensor1":[],
        "sensor2":[],
        "sensor3":[]
    }

    for(i=1; i<=nSize; i++){
        aSensor1.push(i);
        aSensor2.push(i);
        aSensor3.push(i);
    }

    for(n=0; n<nSize; n++){
        var pos1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (nSize-n));
        var pos2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (nSize-n));
        var pos3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (nSize-n));

        var int1 = aSensor1[pos1]; aSensor1.splice(pos1,1);
        var int2 = aSensor2[pos2]; aSensor2.splice(pos2,1);
        var int3 = aSensor3[pos3]; aSensor3.splice(pos3,1);

        lc_relationship.sensor1[int1-1]  = {
            "ObjectID" : "sens1_" + rightPad(int1),
            "Parent":null,
            "child": "sens2_" + rightPad(int2),
            "z cordinate": -5
        } 

        lc_relationship.sensor2[int2-1]  = {
            "ObjectID" : "sens2_" + rightPad(int2),
            "Parent":"sens1_" + rightPad(int1),
            "child": "sens3_" + rightPad(int3),
            "z cordinate": 0
        }

        lc_relationship.sensor3[int3-1]  = {
            "ObjectID" : "sens3_" + rightPad(int3),
            "Parent":"sens2_" + rightPad(int2),
            "child": null,
            "z cordinate": 5
        }


    }

    return lc_relationship;
}

console.log(generateData());
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer. I'm very much thankful for your reply.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sagh0900/z5mMX/6/ , This was the cone geometry I was talking about to dispaly in 10 x 10 grid fashion to let you know you what exactly my intention was.

Comment: OMG! drawing 300 cones like that one is going to be slow jaja, well not sure, I haven't worked with webgl before. Anyway, good luck with that :)

Comment: Could you please customize the algorithm for one to many, i mean an object on one sensor plane has more than one child in its next sensor plane. could you please help with that?

Comment: Sure, but you should make it a new question, since you need to provide more information: how many children will have a 1st layer sensor? and a 2nd layer sensor? is the number of children fixed or is random?

Comment: Yes, I will make a new question soon and provide you the link. But it is quite general, Ist layer should has 100 objects, second layer also has 100 objects (but this time more than object from second layer is children for one object on first layer and same with it third layer). In the process, few objects on first and second layer don't have children but doesn't matter.

Comment: I need some help dude, How can I access child through the parent, like taking child id from parent and accessing child in the sensor2 plane, and also I want to access the parent from grand child - child - parent, I need this help very urgent dude.

Comment: OK: given a 1st layer sensor, you use its child (a string) and iterate throw the 2nd layer array until you get the sensor with the same ObjectId. The same applies for searching a parent. I updated the jsFiddle with a example http://jsfiddle.net/roimergarcia/j2uLE/3/ look at the end of the Javascript code, open the browser's console to see the output.

Comment: Roimer, Thats so great of you. If you would not be here, my work would move further. Thanks for your wonderful help. Here, on console, I could see whole objects are printing. I was trying to print: 

console.log(son.ObjectID); and expecting to print text value: sens3_033 but could able to see any output. Could you please check with that. I also tried to stringify the object but no idea for me :(